# The type initializer for "projData.projDataModule" threw an exception

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio

In visual basic, when in the "frmMain Events: Load", I get the following error

```
The type initializer for 'projData.projDataModule' threw an exception.
```

when running the code:

```
var = 180
```

"var" is defined in projDataModule as

```
Module projDataModule
    Public var As Double
End Module
```

When I rebuild the solution, It says "0 errors, 0 warnings" and will actually compile, however the Error list shows the following error:

```
Error 1 Custom tool error: Failed to generate file: There is an error in XML document (1, 1). I:\Documents and Settings\Bill\Desktop\Projects\Data\My Project\Application.myapp 1 1 Data
```

Application.myapp is an xml file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyApplicationData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MySubMain>true</MySubMain>
  <MainForm>frmMain</MainForm>
  <SingleInstance>false</SingleInstance>
  <ShutdownMode>0</ShutdownMode>
  <EnableVisualStyles>true</EnableVisualStyles>
  <AuthenticationMode>0</AuthenticationMode>
  <SplashScreen>frmSplash</SplashScreen>
  <SaveMySettingsOnExit>true</SaveMySettingsOnExit>
</MyApplicationData>
```

Any ideas or help at all would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I the same problem, but I have multiple project in the same solution so some of them were working and some are not so i traced the XML file between, and i fixed it by changing utf-16 to utf-8

Comment: I tried it, compiled it then return the value to 16 again and compiled it with no error, I m not sure what was happening, I contact Microsoft group and to get more info about what was wrong and what i could be breaking too.